# What is a more elegant way to trim data with jQuery

Tags: jquery, trim

I have the following jQuery code:

`$(myObj).val( $.trim($(myObj).val()) );`

From my experience with jQuery and it's elegant approach to common scripting tasks I feel like jQuery should provide a more elegant way to trim an objects value data. Is there a more elegant way in which the object is not called twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(myObj).val(function(i, val){
  return $.trim(val);
});
```

See [this example](http://api.jquery.com/val/#example-1-1) from the jQuery `val` docs.

Comment: I read the `.val()` docs but missed this in the examples. Thank you for explicitly pointing to it!

Answer (score 0):

Assign it to a variable.

```
var a = $(myObj);
a.val($.trim(a.val()));
```